# Thread which is both notified and interrupted while waiting

Tags: java, multithreading

JLS 17.2.4:

> If a thread ***is*** both notified and interrupted while waiting, it may
>   either:
>
> [...]

Could you give an example of thread which is both interrupted and notified while waiting? I cannot understand how it is even possible because when we call

```
Thred.interrupt()
```

or

```
obj.notify()
```

the thread will be removed from the wait set. Since further call doesn't relate to a waiting thread. It has been removed from wait set yet.

Answer (score 4):

Consider this code:

```
synchronized(obj) {
   obj.notify();
   threadWatingOnObj.interrupt();
}
```

Before the thread executing the above code releases the lock, no notified thread will be able to proceed. Therefore, when control returns to such a thread from its `obj.wait()` call, it will have been both notified and interrupted.

Comment: Not clear. When we invoke either `notify()` or `interrupt()` methods the thread will be removed from wait set, hence it has not been waiting thread yet.

Comment: First of all, there is no guarantee that by the time a call to `notify` or `interrupt` returns, any threads have actually been removed from the wait set, this is an asynchronous operation. Secondly, that fact is not very relevant because what matters is the thread state at the moment of the `wait` call returning. The thread will *deterministically* have been both notified and interrupted by the above code and that fact must be properly reflected. Just think about the consequences on semantics if this weren't so.

Comment: The thing is I haven't found in the JLS that `notify` and `interrupt` are asynchromous operations. Where do you know it?

Comment: Have you found a guarantee in the JLS that the wait set operations are guaranteed to have completed by the time `notify`/`interrupt` complete? Without the guarantee they *may as well* be asynchronous, even if some JVMs implement them synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a question from an exam.  You're supposed to fill in the blank, right?

I think the question is poorly thought out because "interrupted" is a state that a thread can be in, and "waiting" is a state that a thread can be in, but "notified" is not a state.

If a thread calls `wait()` when it is already in the interrupted state, then the wait() call will return an exception.  Likewise, if a thread is in the waiting state when it becomes interrupted, then the wait() call will return an exception in that case too.

Maybe when they say "a thread is both notified and interrupted", they mean that the thread *was* waiting, and it *was* notified, and then an interrupt was delivered while the thread still was in the wait() call, trying to re-acquire the mutex.

I have no inside knowledge of what happens in that case, but based on the Javadoc for `Object.wait()`, I would expect the wait() call to return normally after it acquires the mutex.